# @Valid (jsr 303) not working in Spring mvc 3.0

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'm trying to achieve the JSR 303 bean validation in Spring 3.0 by using a simple login use case. The problem is if I submit the form without any value the validation is not happening (i.e the BindingResult method hasErrors() always returning 'false' and printing *I'm cool !*. Following is the code snippet:

```
@Controller
public class AnnotatedController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "login")
    public String validateLogin(@Valid LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(result.hasErrors())
            System.out.println("Got Errors !");
        else
            System.out.println("I'm cool !");
        return "login";
    }
}
```

The bean looks like this :

```
    public class LoginForm {
    @NotEmpty
    private String userName;
    @Size(min=2, max=3)
    private String password;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Finally the view:

```
<table>
    <form:form action="login.htm" modelAttribute="loginForm">
        <tr>
            <td>User :</td>
            <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Ok"> </tr>
    </form:form>
</table>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Just want to validate - Can you please confirm how you have configured Spring-MVC, I am assuming that you have used `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` or you may have explicitly specified the HandlerAdapter - if you have explicitly specified the handlerAdapter you may need to specify the validator(JSR 303) also explicitly.

Comment: @BijuKunjummen Yes, I have configured it using <mvc:annotation-driven/>. Is there anything else that I should do here ?

Comment: Yes, if you are using mvc:annotation-driven, you don't need to do anything else. Can you please also confirm that you have a JSR 303 implementation in your classpath - say hibernate-validator jar files?

Comment: @BijuKunjummen Yeah, I have hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar & validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar present in my Eclipse Web App library.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`in servlet context XML fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing form error tag.use like

```
<table>
<form:form action="login.htm" commandName="logindetails">
    <tr>
        <td>User :</td>
        <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
        <td><form:errors path="userName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password :</td>
        <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
        <td><form:errors path="password"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Ok"> </tr>
</form:form>
```

and also you have to maintain property file with error message.

```
NotEmpty.logindetails.userName = userName is required!
Range.logindetails.password= password value must be between 2 and 3
```

Example: 
Click [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/)